# iTunes on iMac won't start up after upgrade (error -10699)

Tags: macos, itunes, imac

Yesterday I updated iTunes in my iMac running OS X 10.10.3. According to the information in App Store, the new iTunes version is 12.1.2.

Since then iTunes won't start up. If I click on it, there is no response.

I figured that there is probably a known problem with the upgrade, and that this would be fixed in due course. However, I've been monitoring discussions, and there does not seem to be anything else who is having this problem.

Some research I did on how to solve this problem was to trash the iTunes preferences, and to download and re-install iTunes: I did both, but it still won't start up.

Nothing is logged on any error logs as far as I can see. I did a "tail -f /var/log/system.log" in Terminal App and then attempted to start iTunes, no messages were displayed.

When I try and open iTunes from terminal ("open -a iTunes"), I get a message:
"LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/iTunes.app with error -10699."

Open With Role sounds as if there might be a permissions problem, I've repaired permissions with Disk Utility, and I've also tried starting iTunes from the command line using sudo, but no luck.

At this stage I've run out of ideas. Anybody else have an idea what I could try?

Comment: did you restart ?

Comment: Just installed the iTunes 12.1.2.27 update on my MBA 10.9.5 and it starts without problems.

Comment: Opening from Terminal "open -a iTunes" also works without problem.

Comment: @Buscar웃: I restarted multiple times.

Thanks for the feedback that it works fine on your iMac. I had hoped that it other people with iMacs had the same issue (just to be sure: the upgrade worked fine on my Macbook, I encounter the problem on my iMac) but the problem seems to be specific to my machine. Ah well...

Comment: I tried to edit my comment above but I only had 5 minutes, Grrrr..
I wanted to say that the upgrade actually worked fine on my MBP as well. I was wondering whether the upgrade worked on other iMacs.

Comment: Did you try it after logging in as different user ?

Comment: @Buscar웃: Yes, logging in as a different user produced the same result (ie iTunes is not starting up).

Comment: I have the same problem here. OS X 10.10.3, iTunes 12.1.2. I tried moving ~/{Music,Library}/iTunes to elsewhere, deleting plists, and killing iTunes Helper, but they didn't help.

Comment: @Jakkals: try `/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes` in your Terminal, this worked for me.

Comment: @uasi: Yay! Starting it this way in terminal works for me as well! Thank you very much. Btw, how did you figure out how to fix this? And do you have any insight as to the root cause (do we have something wrong on our iMacs, or is there probably a bug in the upgraded version of iTunes)?

Comment: @Jakkals: No idea, just followed an instruction someone said in [a tweet](https://twitter.com/nkym37/status/586815757012439040). Anyway we now have a solution, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I'm in the same boat on a 2013 MacBook Pro. The binary launch works for me, but everything you described is exactly what I'm seeing. I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I was running the Public Beta of 10.10.3 prior to final release.

Comment: Same boat here with a 2013 Retina MBP. I've tried repairing the disk and perms as well. Going to try a "repair" install from recovery partition and report back. I was running the developer seed of 10.10.3 also (could be related).

Comment: FWIW, I was **not** running Beta of 10.10.3, so we do not have that in common.

Comment: **Update:** Just did a reinstall from recovery partition (not a clean install) to no avail. :(

Comment: Try `sudo xattr -c /Applications/iTunes.app`. It worked for me.

Comment: Aleksandr's tip worked for me.  I'm on 10.10.4, and this just 'broke' a few days ago - no idea why - no new installations or upgrades or anything.  the sudo xattr line worked just fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it by deleting iTunes and reinstalling.

The Finder tries quite hard to stop you from deleting iTunes; instead you can open Terminal.app and 'sudo rm -rf /Applications/iTunes.app'. You can download the replacement copy of iTunes from https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/

Comment: Have you encountered any side-effects from this?

Comment: I've changed this to be the correct answer. The solution proposed by @uasi was temporary, as he (she?) himself admitted. Following the instructions in this answer resulted in my problem being solved.

Comment: This worked for me too! It seems that the key is to to remove iTunes.app at first. Without removing it reinstallation resulted in nothing.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Loads for about 10 seconds and then crashes.

Comment: Wait, I launched it again and it appears to be stable.... (So, I uninstalled it, reinstalled it, ran it once (crashes), and then ran it a second time (stable).

Comment: This worked for me, just upgraded to OSX 10.10 and iTunes wouldn't open.  Redownloaded iTunes and tried installing over the top of the old one, but only deleting in Terminal worked for me as Shadowphiar says.

Comment: Its sad that you have to do this to fix it. Apple really dropped the ball on this one.

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary solution, you can execute iTunes binary directly by doing `/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes` in the terminal.

Code `-10699` returned by `open -a iTunes` indicates some error in Launch Services (similar error codes [are documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/index.html) but the very thing is not). Executing binary in this way somehow sidesteps the problem.