# LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/darktable.app with error -10810

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, permission

Darktable mysteriously stopped working on me yesterday.  I tried restarting my iMac, deleting and re-installing darkable and finally after going through some forums I tried running through the terminal:
    `open -a darktable`

That returned
`LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/photo programs/darktable.app with error -10810`
I tried `chmod +x /Applications/darktable.app/Contents/MacOS/darktable`
I also tried `chmod +x '/Applications/photo programs/darktable.app/'`

I have tried with several versions of Darktable and am beginning to think it has nothing to do with Darktable and something to do with MacOS...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution... Here is how I found it: I tried the temporary solution suggested in this post:
[iTunes on iMac won't start up after upgrade (error -10699)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180538/itunes-on-imac-wont-start-up-after-upgrade-error-10699)
- execute the binary directly by running the binary in the terminal.

```
/Applications/darktable.app/Contents/MacOS/darktable
```

That gave me this error:

```
[init] the database lock file contains a pid that seems to be alive in your system: 456
[init] database is locked, probably another process is already using it
```

As stated in http://redmine.darktable.org/issues/10164, there was a lock file left behind in  /Users/{HOME_USER}/.config/darktable/library.db.lock.

**All I had to do was delete that file** and up it was running again... Sometimes it's just a little too simple. :/